# #1054 - Unknown column 'purchasedetail.itemId' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql

I have an error in `purchasedetail` table when I am trying to fetch this record. This is my select query:

```
SELECT itemstock.itemId
  FROM  itemstock
  JOIN item ON item.itemId = purchasedetail.itemId
  JOIN purchasemaster ON purchasemaster.purchaseMasterId = purchasedetail.purchaseMasterId
  JOIN purchasedetail ON purchasedetail.itemId = item.itemId
  JOIN party ON party.partyId = purchasemaster.partyId
WHERE
  purchasemaster.partyId = ".$_REQUEST['partyId']."
  AND itemstock.quantity > 0
GROUP BY itemName,itemCode
```

This is the error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'purchasedetail.itemId' in 'on clause'
```

Comment: Does the table `purchasedetail` have a column called `itemId`? It doesn't, does it? That's why it's an unknown column - just like the error says.

Comment: You have `itemstock` in the `FROM` clause, but it does not appear to be joined with any other tables.

Comment: Are you missing a `JOIN` between `item` and `itemstock`?

Comment: ok so i have to join itemstock also

Comment: yes purchasedetail  have itemId column   @h2ooooooo

Comment: i am trying to join itemstock also it is give me another error 
#1054 - Unknown column 'purchasedetail.itemId' in 'on clause'

SELECT itemstock.itemId
  FROM itemstock 
JOIN item ON item.itemId = purchasedetail.itemId 
JOIN itemstock AS k ON k.itemId = item.itemId 
JOIN purchasemaster ON purchasemaster.purchaseMasterId = purchasedetail.purchaseMasterId 
JOIN purchasedetail ON purchasedetail.itemId = item.itemId 
JOIN party ON party.partyId = purchasemaster.partyId 
WHERE purchasemaster.partyId = 5 
AND itemstock.quantity > 0 
GROUP BY itemName,itemCode

Answer (score 1):

When joining tables, the columns you join "on" have to belong to those tables. You are trying to join on columns from other tables that you haven't mentioned yet. Try this:

```
SELECT itemstock.itemId 
FROM itemstock 
JOIN item ON item.itemId = itemstock.itemId 
JOIN purchasedetail ON purchasedetail.itemId = item.itemId 
JOIN purchasemaster ON purchasemaster.purchaseMasterId = purchasedetail.purchaseMasterId 
JOIN party ON party.partyId = purchasemaster.partyId 
WHERE purchasemaster.partyId = 5 AND itemstock.quantity > 0 GROUP BY itemName,itemCode
```